# GIT clone not working

Tags: git, github, tortoisehg

I am trying to get the latest [NHibernate source from GitHub](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core) using the latest Tortoise Hg client using the read only string provided, get the following error:

```
% hg clone --verbose -- git://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core.git
repository git://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core.git not found
[command returned code 255 Wed Sep 07 08:01:23 2011]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't know mercurial can be used to clone git repositories...

Comment: Charles: yes, it can, using the `hg-git` plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using mercurial (hg) to try to clone a git repository. Try using git or install [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using `git clone` for cloning git repository?

`git clone --verbose git://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core.git`